# Debug Netbeans mutiple Maven projects (javascript)

Tags: maven, debugging, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans and developping Maven projects running through a Karaf server.

I already know how to debug the back-end part with netbeans since I can attach the debugger via dt_socket but I'd like to debug the javascript part aswell directly from Netbeans without having to use Chrome debugging tool.

Note that the Maven projects containing the front pages are not HTML5 netbeans applications.

Any ideas on how to achieve that ?